# Is there a Bignum module for Ocaml?

Tags: ocaml

I've done some searching around and apparently there used to be a Bignum module in the standard library according to [this](http://alan.petitepomme.net/cwn/2004.05.11.html#5)  But at this point I don't see anything in the standard library.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no bignum module in the core OCaml distribution. The [official recommendation](https://ocaml.org/releases/4.11/htmlman/libnum.html) is to use the third-party [`Zarith` library](https://github.com/ocaml/Zarith), specifically its [`Z` module](https://antoinemine.github.io/Zarith/doc/latest/Z.html).

If you've installed OCaml as part of your operating system distribution, see if it has a package for Zarith. For example, on Debian, Ubuntu and derivatives, it's [`libzarith-ocaml-dev`](https://packages.debian.org/sid/libzarith-ocaml-dev). If Zarith isn't available through your operating system, install it with OPAM:

```
opam install zarith
```

When building your application, compile with one of

```
ocamlc -I +zarith zarith.cma …
ocamlopt -I +zarith zarith.cmxa …
ocamlfind <COMMAND> -package zarith -linkpkg …
```

To use Zarith in the toplevel:

```
ocaml -I +zarith zarith.cma zarith_top.cma
```

Older versions of Ocaml had a bignum module in the standard distribution (but not in the standard library: it didn't require separate installation, but had to be linked explicitly). It was the [`nums` library](https://ocaml.org/releases/4.05/htmlman/libnum.html), and its main module `Num`. Since [OCaml 4.06](https://ocaml.org/releases/4.06/htmlman/libnum.html), the `nums` library is [distributed separately](https://github.com/ocaml/num).

Technically, there is no bignum module in the standard library, because the standard library in Ocaml terminology is the default library that programs are compiled against, and there's no bignum module in that. Nor is there a `Bignum` library — because the bignum library is called [`nums`](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual036.html), and its main module is called `Num`. It has been part of the standard Ocaml distribution since before Ocaml was called Ocaml, and still is.

Comment: This is an old question with old answers.  A FYI for anyone finding it now: [`num`](https://opam.ocaml.org/packages/num/) has been superseded.  According to [https://github.com/ocaml/num](https://github.com/ocaml/num), "New applications that need arbitrary-precision arithmetic should use the Zarith library (https://github.com/ocaml/Zarith) instead of the Num library, and older applications that already use Num are encouraged to switch to Zarith. Zarith delivers much better performance than Num and has a nicer API."  [`bignum`](https://opam.ocaml.org/packages/bignum) is a wrapper around Zarith.

Answer (score 9):

You are looking for the `num` library. Technically this is not part of the "Standard Library", but is part of the standard distribution. Thus, simply compile with this library, and it will be available. Also, you might be interested in the new [zarith](http://forge.ocamlcore.org/projects/zarith/) library. I am unsure how the two compare.

Comment: On Frama-C's value analysis, that uses big integers in several places, (to represent the analyzed program's integers, but also to represent offsets as part of its memory model), switching from `Big_int` to Zarith gains 50% of memory and 33% of execution time. A pure integer benchmarks with only small integers shows a 8x speedup for Zarith. (`Big_int` is 32x slower than `int`, and Zarith is 3.9x slower than `int`).

Comment: I notice that Zarith is from Xavier Leroy.  Given it's advantages over the current Big_int it seems like Zarith should become part of the standard distribution, anyone know if that's planned?

Comment: @aneccodeal Well, there is the dependency on GMP. It is very likely that Zarith will eventually be integrated into OCaml, but Xavier will probably want to wait until all problems have been ironed out. So use it now (and let others know about it) so that it will be integrated faster :)

Answer (score 4):

To add to the other answers, the general arbitrary precision module is `Num` (it includes big integers and big rational numbers). There is separately a [`Big_int`](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Big_int.html) module for just big integers; the `Big_int` module is used by `Num` for its big integer support, but if you need just big integers and not fractions, you can just use `Big_int` directly. Both are part of the `num` library.