# Why does a factorial function gives me a negative number

Tags: math, ocaml

I made a factorial function permitting me to calculate factorials of course and as we know, a factorial **can never be < 0**. And my code gives me some times negative numbers... Here it is:

```
exception FactorialError of string;;
let rec factorial (n: int) : int = (
  if n < 0 then raise (FactorialError "The number has to be upper or equal then 0");
  if n == 0 then 1 else n * factorial(n-1);
);;

let value = ref (1);;
for i = 0 to 100 do
(
  value := factorial i;
  if !value = 0 then raise (FactorialError ("Factorial is no more possible after i = " ^ 
string_of_int i)) else print_string ("i: " ^ string_of_int i);
  print_string "\nValue: ";
  print_int !value;
  print_string "\n";
)
done;;
```

And here are the results for some of them only:

```
i: 0
Value: 1

i: 1
Value: 1

...

i: 20
Value : 2432902008176640000

i: 21
Value : -4249290049419214848 // <- Here is the problem
```

... Here is the problem but not only for the 21 value but also for many other...

Comment: Looks like *integer overflow*: when integer exceeds its MaxValue you get *negative* result

Comment: Related: [How to present big_int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10515033/how-to-present-big-int) and [Is there a Bignum module for Ocaml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680499/is-there-a-bignum-module-for-ocaml)

Answer (score 1):

You have an *integer overflow*. Please, note that `64`bit signed integer must be within

```
[-9223372036854775808 .. 9223372036854775807]
```

range. If you go *beyond* the ranges, you'll get *incorrect* value:

```
2432902008176640000 * 21 == 51090942171709440000 > 9223372036854775807
```

If you want to compute *exact* factorial value, have a look at *arbitrary precision integer* [big_int](https://v2.ocaml.org/releases/4.04/htmlman/libref/Big_int.html)

Comment: Ok thank you very much, but how should I use the big_int type because my code refuse it... Is it the `module Big_int: sig .. end` that we have to add ? And moreover, I tried to replace each int by an int64 but an error appears, something like : Type expected is int but there is an int64... Have you any idea ?

Comment: @Pax: you already have `64`bit integer, there's no need in `int64`. Yes, you have to use some module to work with arbitrary precision integers; https://ocaml.org/docs/modules

Comment: It may be worth noting that on a 64-bit machine, `int` in OCaml is _63_ bits. It doesn't make much difference in this situation, but it's worth knowing.

Comment: big_int API from the num package is deprecated and has been superseded by zarith.

Answer (score 1):

Here is code that uses the `Big_int` module to calculate a large factorial value:

```
$ cat bigfact.ml
open Big_int

let rec big_fact n =
    if n < 2 then unit_big_int
    else
        mult_big_int (big_int_of_int n) (big_fact (n - 1))
```

Use the function to calculate `big_fact 100`:

```
$ ocaml nums.cma
OCaml version 4.14.0
Enter #help;; for help.

# #use "bigfact.ml";;
val big_fact : int -> Big_int.big_int = <fun>
# string_of_big_int (big_fact 100);;
- : string =
    "93326215443944152681699238856266700490
     71596826438162146859296389521759999322
     99156089414639761565182862536979208272
     23758251185210916864000000000000000000
     000000"
```

For what it's worth, I believe the `Big_int` module is being replaced by the newer `Zarith` module.

Answer (score 1):

What happened is that OCaml's `int` is a **machine int**; more efficient, and closer to the hardware than representations chosen by e.g. some popular scripting languages, but with one caveat: Machine ints are limited (modulo) 2<sup>64</sup> or 2<sup>32</sup>, **the size of a machine word**.

OCaml ints are [further limited](https://ocaml.org/docs/first-hour#types) because they're [tagged](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_pointer), this is great for efficiency in a garbage-collected language, as it's a very simple way to avoid a huge number of allocations. This however means they're modulo 2<sup>63</sup>.
`int` is also *signed*, that is, half what could be represented with 2<sup>63</sup> numbers is reserved to negative numbers.

This all means that when you're using `int`, your values can only be in range [-4611686018427387904, 4611686018427387904), from -2<sup>62</sup> up to but not including 2<sup>62</sup>.
Lucky for you, you don't have to think about all this, because OCaml exposes `Int.(min_int, max_int)`, readily calculated for you based on your platform. If you anticipate your application will need a wider range than what OCaml provides with `int`, you look for something more elaborate. 21! happens to be outside of this range.

That "something more elaborate" would be [infinite precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) or memory-backed integers. The [Z module](https://ocaml.org/p/zarith/latest/doc/Z/index.html) from [ocaml/zarith](https://github.com/ocaml/Zarith) is the standard OCaml implementation of this data structure.

Here's how we'll use Zarith, assuming we have a project setup that relies on `opam` and `dune`:

1. `opam install -y zarith` will bring you the package locally so that you can use it in your projects.
2. add a `(libraries zarith)`, or add `zarith` to an existent `(libraries ...)` field to the `dune` file next to the module that uses zarith.
3. you'll be able to implement `fac` like this:

```ml
let rec zfac n =
  if Z.Compare.(n = zero) then Z.one 
  else Z.(n * zfac (pred n))

let fac n =
  if n < 0 then invalid_arg "fac n where n < 0" 
  else zfac Z.(of_int n)
```

Notice that the error case is checked only once, outside of the recursive function, and that I'm using `=` (or its opposite, `<>`) and avoiding `==`, as it and `!=` are physical equality operators rather than *structural* equality operators: they check if two things are in the same spot in memory, so they'll often give you unexpected results. Try for yourself: `let x = [1;2] and y = [1;2] in x == y`, this will be `false`, because x and y occupy different spots in memory!
There was also no need to use extra parenthesis or specify the types. You'll find such style niceties in documents online, I suggest OCaml [guidelines](https://ocaml.org/docs/guidelines) and [best practices](https://ocaml.org/docs/best-practices).

Now, if you use e.g. `Z.to_string` in a toplevel to check the value of `fac 21`, you'll find the correct answer: 51090942171709440000

Alternatively if you're just trying things out in a REPL, and you've done at least step 1 from above, you can enter `#require "zarith";;` and play with the library interactively.